# CMAKE terminal command linux

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu14.04 and cmake version 3.20.1

From the GitHub link:
https://github.com/sccn/labstreaminglayer/wiki/INSTALL

Terminal Command:
cmake --build . --config Release --target install

I tried to use this command for installing the applications, however, the guideline mentions that there will be an 'install' folder inside the 'build' folder, however, it did not appear.
I also have trouble understanding this line of code. I will appreciate it if anyone could explain this command line and solve the problem for me.

Comment: Hi, all the building and installation are correct, there is no error message, however, there is no install folder as expected in the build folder as I mentioned in the question

Comment: "the guideline mentions that there will be an 'install' folder inside the 'build' folder" - I haven't found this note in the reference you show us. But I have found that note: "This will create a distribution tree in the folder specified by CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX*". On Ubuntu (and many other Linux disctributions) default value for `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is `/usr/local`.